# R: count how many elements of a vector are are present in each sublist of a nested list

Tags: r

I am working with some data in `R`, and have a vector (e.g. list of genes) that I want to know how many members of this vector occur in sublists of a list-of-list (e.g. lists of genes that are expressed at different time points). 
I can do this manually by checking `x[] %in% y[[]]` or `is.element(x[], y[[]])` but am trying to figure out how to write an R function to do this for me because I have a few of these vectors and long lists. 
Here's a toy example:

```
mylist <- list("Hr01" = c("G0295801", "G0295799", "G0293928", "G0293730", "G0293626", "G0293536", "G0293364", "G0291640", "G0291233", "G0290907"), "Hr02" =c ("G0295801", "G0295701", "G0295689", "G0293730", "G0293626", "G0293364", "G0293360", "G0293276", "G0293066", "G0292860", "G0292814", "G0292028", "G0292014", "G0291824"), "Hr03" = c("G0295701", "G0293364", "G0293276", "G0291714", "G0291253", "G0290405", "G0290259", "G0289553", "G0284885"))

checklist <- as.vector(c("G0290907", "G0295701", "G0270472", "G0283625", "G0284885"))
```

It would be could to get something like this as output (data frame, with columns: name of sublist, how many members of `checklist` occur in sublists of `mylist`) :

```
"Hr01" 1
"Hr02" 1
"Hr03" 2
```

I'd greatly appreciate any help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Combining `lapply` and `rbind` should do it.  Where for each list element you are counting the number of the sub-elements are in your checklist and then simply combining the results in to a matrix.

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(mylist, function(x) sum(x %in% checklist)))

     [,1]
Hr01    1
Hr02    1
Hr03    2
```

Comment: Glad to help, don't forget to accept the answer if this works for you.

Answer (score 3):

Another option is

```
 mapply(function(x,y) sum(x %in% y),  mylist, list(checklist))
 #Hr01 Hr02 Hr03 
 #1    1    2
```

Or as @Frank suggested

```
  sapply(mylist,function(y) sum(checklist %in% y))
  #Hr01 Hr02 Hr03 
  # 1    1    2
```

Or

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
unnest(mylist, group) %>%
           group_by(group) %>% 
           summarise(count=sum(x %in% checklist))
#   group count
#1  Hr01     1
#2  Hr02     1
#3  Hr03     2
```

Comment: `sapply` makes more sense, since you don't need to iterate over both `mylist` and `checklist`; the latter is just recycled. `sapply(mylist,function(y) sum(checklist %in% y))`

Answer (score 1):

Take look at what `lapply` produces with "%in% and then get the count by `sum`-ming the logical vectors:

```
lapply(mylist, "%in%", checklist)
#--------
$Hr01
 [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE

$Hr02
 [1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

$Hr03
[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
#----------

 sapply( lapply(mylist, "%in%", checklist), sum)
Hr01 Hr02 Hr03 
   1    1    2
```